How to encode polylines from routes with leg?
I am facing a problem in python someone can help me with.
I have a polyline and am using googleMaps API.
The polyline is as:

I am encofing the polyline with:
encoded_polyline = googlemaps.convert.encode_polyline([step['end_location'] for step in polyline])

The result:
ycvhGila_@fEkEzAfEhJrHbTlg@zzArMxlCzeA_FSiGwNrMwUrvOu`IeVjeq@aTvpE{AfJ}d@sQwo@}Th@hIEvf@y\\nR

It can be tested here :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/polylinedecoder
As you can see there are no legs and route direction.
Does anyone know where I might have done a mistake please?
Many thanks in advance.

Why do you expect an encoded polyline to include route directions?

To be able to draw the polyline with the directions. Am I misunderstanding?
